# Global static variable or shared preference android

Tags: java, android

My Android project need share a `List<Right> rights` between Activities. The value of this list is initiated in LoginActivity. In other Activity, i use this list to check right of user (if user has a correspondence right, app will show correspondence tab or do something else). The problem i meet is how to store `List<Right> rights` in my Android application. I have read many Post and people use Gson and Flexjson to change this list to String and use `SharedPreferences.Editor putString (String key,String value)` to store in SharedPreferences. In other Activity,  use `preferences.getString("girl_heart_key", "DEFAULT");` to get String and Deserialize it to `List<Right> rights`. But i think we can use a global static variable:

```
public static List<RightObject>rights = new ArrayList<RightObject>();
```

to share  `List<RightObject>rights` between Activities.
My question is: can we use global static variable to replace SharePrefrence in this case? and Is there any risk( about performance, security or memory) ?

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624671/how-shared-preference-can-be-differ-from-static-global-variable-of-one-class

Answer (score 3):

NO, it's not recommended to do it.

global static variable has same lifetime as your `Application`, data will be destroyed once `Application` is finished. `SharedPreference` on the other hand can persist the data until user has `clear the storage/cache` of your app through app settings.

The better approach is to have a `Repository` that can be shared as a `DataSource` for your application.

In case you accidentally have a `static` reference to a `Context`, than there will be a memory leak.

see more [Android : Static Fields and Memory Leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks)